# Extracting drawing tools hand entered annotations

Tags: graphics, front-end, notebooks

Once one adds annotations to a Graphics[] with drawing tools, is it possible to extract the annotations only so they can be stenciled over a different Graphics[]?

Dan

Answer (score 3):

Use `Group` from the right-click menu to group your annotations and select `Copy Graphics Selection` from the right-click menu. Then you can paste the selected objects into a new cell or into an existing graphics object.

[image]